# MYSQL delete record after 15 minute if some value doesn't exists

Tags: mysql

I googled a lot, but Unsuccessfully.

Can someone give me an idea, how to make that, Mysql automaticly delete record after 15 minute, if some value doesn't exists in record?

Comment: Use a cron job that executes a PHP script to see if a record is older than 15 minutes and checks your missing value.

Comment: I doubt that this is a supported feature, one way to do this is to create a server process that works every n minutes and perform this function. You need to be able to identify target rows quickly so that the process is efficient. Also, you need to prevent users of the system (in case there is more than 1) from associating rows from other tables to such a row, otherwise they may turn to orphans or get deleted to.

Comment: If I use cron job it will check all the time and I think it's bad for performance. I want something after insert record, like trigger. 
I want something like this:
after insert data call function in 15 minute and the function will check if eists value

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a caretaker script that runs every X hours?

That would delete the rows.

But make the software ignore these rows beforehand if they are invalid